# We turn cards simultaneously from two well shuffled decks. Exact match means same card from each deck. Find probability of at least one exact match.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, inclusion-exclusion, card-games

**Problem**
Suppose we turn over cards simultaneously from two well shuffled decks of ordinary playing cards. We say we obtain an exact match on a particular turn if the same card appears from each deck; for example, the queen of spades against the queen of spades. Let $p_M$ equal the probability of at least one exact match.

- Show that $$p_M=1-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4!}+...-\frac{1}{52!}$$
  **Hint:** Let $C_i$ denote the event of an exact match on the $i^{th}$ turn. Then $p_M = P(C_1 \cup C_2 \ldots C_{52})$ Now use the the general inclusion-exclusion formula. Note that $P(C_i) = \frac1{52}$. And, hence $p_1=52(1/52)$.
- Show that $p_m$ is approximately equal to $1-e^{-1}=0.632$

I do not understand why $p_1=52(1/52)$, could someone explain to me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Read about [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Answer (score 2):

I think $$p_1 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{52} \mathbb{P}(C_i) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{52} \frac{1}{52} = 52 \cdot \frac{1}{52} = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different way of thinking about it.

A derangement is an arrangement with no cards in the same position.  If we don't get a derangement then at least 1 card matches.

And the probability we get a derangement is the number of derangement over the number of arrangements $\frac {!52}{52!}$

And the probability that at we don't get a derangement is $1 - \frac {!52}{52!}$

How do count derangements?

First we count all of the arrangements the deck.  Then we subtract all of the arrangements that fix at least 1 card $-{52\choose 1}(51!)$
But we have counted arrangements that fix two cards twice, so we must add one set back in $+{52\choose 2} 50!$ this is "exclusion-inclusion," and we must keep passing this along for all numbers of fixed cards.

$!52 = 52! - {52\choose 1}51! + {52\choose 2} 50! + \cdots + (-1)^k{52\choose k}(52-k)! + \cdots = \sum_\limits{k=0}^{52} (-1)^k\frac {52!}{(52-k)!}$

$\frac {!52}{52!} = \sum_\limits{k=0}^{52} (-1)^k\frac {1}{k!} \approx e^{-1}$

$1-\frac {!52}{52!} = 1-\sum_\limits{k=0}^{52} (-1)^k\frac {1}{k!} = \sum_\limits{k=1}^{52} (-1)^{k-1}\frac {1}{k!} \approx 1-
 e^{-1}$